# access array key with registered trademark

Tags: php, arrays, key, symbols

I am trying to access an array value by using a key. My code works fine except when there is a registered trademark in the key. How do I get around this?

```
$map = array(
    'Education'=>'643',
    'STORMS®'=>'644',
);

print $csv_line[$i];        // prints STORMS®
print $map[$csv_line[$i]];  // prints nothing
print $map['STORMS®'];      // prints the value I need
```

Comment: I haven't yet reproduced this problem. [example](http://viper-7.com/v7KPKQ) If it appears fine in the browser, you're probably getting the (R) HTML entity and not the character itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is html special character, you can `preg_replace or str_replace` it if you want.

> registered trademark **can be called by** & #174; **OR**  & reg;

[special character](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php), [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), [normalizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php)

---

```
$Content = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$Content);
```